# Are case and default considered statements?

Tags: c

In C specification `case` and `default` keywords are indicated in the section 6.8.1
as Labeled statements:

```
labeled-statement:
identiﬁer : statement
**case** constant-expression : statement
**default** : statement
```

like, for example, `if` and `switch` are indicated in the section 6.8.4 
as Selection statements:

```
selection-statement:
**if** ( expression ) statement
**if** ( expression ) statement **else** statement
**switch** ( expression ) statement
```

These keywords are all written in **bold** so at a first glance I can suppose that
`case`, `default`, `if`, `else` and `switch` are all considered like "statements".

However, after, is written:

```
If a switch statement has an associated case or default label within the scope of an
identiﬁer with a variably modiﬁed type, the entire switch statement shall be within the
scope of that identiﬁer
```

so it seems that `case` and `default` are considered as "label" and not as "statements".

I don't understand which is the correct terminology or if `case` and `default` are statements or labels.

Comment: They are statement according to MS, [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66k51h7a.aspx)

Comment: @Yann Referring to MS in a discussion about the C standard is completely irrelevant. MS does not know or care about the standard.

Comment: I don't see the problem with this question. It's pretty straightforward, asking if `case` and `default` are statements or labels. While it seems a simple misreading of the spec (`case expression:` is a label, while the entire `case expression: statement` is a labeled statement), it seems like a valid programming question with a definite answer.

Comment: @tvanfosson, yes I really don't understand. What do you think about? How is better consider them?

Comment: @xdevel2000 `case` and `default` are, in themselves, labels. They are labels that define a particular kind of labeled statement - often called a "case statement" (default being just one of possibly many cases).

Answer (score 1):

It's quite clear, I don't see what the confusion is.

C99 6.8.1/2

> A `case` or `default` label shall appear only in a `switch` statement.

You're quoting just the title of **6.8.1 Labeled statements**.

Comment: I rewrite my question more clearly, I hope... If you can read it again, thanks.